# $Var(Q)=2\ tr(A\Sigma A\Sigma)+4\mu^TA\Sigma A\mu$

Tags: multivariate-analysis, descriptive-statistics, matrix, covariance-matrix, matrix-decomposition

> Suppose $X\sim N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$ . $A$ is a $p\times p$ symmetric matrix . $Q$ is defined as $Q=X^TAX$. Also $Y$ be defined as $Y=X-\mu$.
>
> Show that $Var(Q)=2\ tr(A\Sigma A\Sigma)+4\mu^TA\Sigma A\mu$

Can someone help ? Should spectral decomposition of $A$ into eigen-values and eigenvectors be of any help?..

(I first tried to break down everything into Double-summation, so as to remove any vector of matrix, but didnt yield anything useful)

Comment: Since $Y$ is defined but never referenced, could there be a typographical error in this question?

Comment: @whuber No no.. There was another part of the question, which i could solve so i didn't post here. It was to show that $$Cov(a^tY,Y^TAY)=0$$ for any fixed $a\in \Bbb{R}^p$

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427332/variance-of-quadratic-form-for-multivariate-normal-distribution